# Followers of followers in twitter 4j

Tags: java, twitter, graph, graph-theory, twitter4j

I want to find out if my followers follow each other using Twitter4j, and build a graph from this. I have Two questions:

**My first Question:**
How do I get this data?

**Second Question:**
How do I visualise this on to a graph with nodes and vertices to show how connected my network is?

Ive tried to get my followers followers who are following me:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        User u1 = null ;
          long cursor = -1;
          IDs ids;
          System.out.println("Listing followers's ids.");
          do {
                  ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs("2289869045", cursor);
              for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
                  System.out.println(id);
                  User user = twitter.showUser(id);
                  System.out.println(user.getName());
              }
          } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);

    }
```

But this doesnt even work right now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Nope because im stuck?

Comment: Or maybe I'm a person who was trying to improve your question, but was confused by your apparently contradictory statements. I'm sorry if that came out as "smart arse."

Comment: apparently? So you're confused yourself then. Well, there was nothing contradictory about what I was saying. It's straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question: You should combine calls on these two twitter API endPoints

- [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup)
- [followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids)

Process should be:

1. Get all of your followers
2. For each of your followers, get theirs
3. Filter out to keep only the edges between members of your graph.

For the second question:

You can have a look at [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) , [gephi](http://gephi.org/) or [d3.js](http://d3js.org/).